# how to manually set a port forward rule?

Tags: portforwarding, vscode-remote

vscode port-forward rule is auto-generate or edit by user via vscode-GUI，
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEits.png)

how to manually set a port forward rule by config-file or code?  (we try to write a config file to determine the port forward rule)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.